# ORM (Eloquente) em Laravel 5.x VS arquitetura de microserviços. Como desenvolver serviços web usando Eloquente que consomem end-points de uma API?

Tags: laravel, api

Considere a seguinte arquitetura:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é um modelo bem moderno onde a API oferece end-points para diferentes serviços fazerem transações com o banco de dados.

Sou um usuário begginer em Laravel, logo a minha dúvida é de iniciante em relação ao Framework.

O Laravel, assim como outros frameworks como Simfony por exemplo, possuem um poderoso ORM que salva muito tempo de desenvolvimento. No Laravel o Eloquente parece ser tbm a base de muitas outras comodidades como migrations, seeds, camadas de autenticações, entre outras.

Se a idéia anterior for verdadeira, me parece ser lógica a conclusão de que se decidirmos não usar o ORM do Laravel, ou as migrations vamos perder boa parte do poderio do Laravel.

Por outro lado, pensando no esquema do desenho acima, como seria a implementação de um **Web Site/APP** que somente consome end-points de uma **API**? No momento eu estou usando [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) para fazer uso das end-points. Mas nesse caso, o meu Web **Site/APP** não vai ter necessidade do ORM, nem Eloquente e nem vou precisar de seeds nem migrations. Então parece lógico que nesse cenário eu estarei perdendo as vantagens do Laravel.

E se essa conclusão for verdadeira, inevitavelmente serei obrigado a questionar a vantagem do Laravel para os desenhos de arquitetura não monolítica.

Até mesmo dentro da API-Restful onde eu poderia usar todas as comodidades do ORM a utilização do Laravel fica questionável pois aqui eu não precisarei das views, não vou utilizar blade e tbm todo o pacote de comodidades associadas.

Talvez por isso exista uma versão ligth do laravel para tratar o desenvolvimento de APIs, o [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.4), que, segundo o seu [website](https://lumen.laravel.com/), nos traz a vantagem de ter algo em torno de 1900 conexões por segundo. Mas tbm existem outras opções para o desenvolvimento de APIs com php tais como o [Phalcon](https://phalconphp.com/pt/), além do Lumen, que são consideradas frameworks php de alta performance. Além disso existe a possibilidade de se usar o Javascript com o NodeJs para desenvolver a integralidade da API. O objetivo aqui deste post (que é a minha dúvida), não é discuti a performance de cada uma dessas opções ou qualificar quem é pior ou melhor.

O fato é que **parece** que o framework Laravel 5.x (5.4 é o que estou usando agora) não parece ser tbm a escolha adequada para criar a **API** (se for escolhido ser feito em PHP).

Ora, se para criar o **Web Site/APP** o Laravel, que não vai usar o ORM e suas comodidades, parece não ter sentido, e para a criação da **API** o Laravel parece tbm não ser a primeira escolha, teríamos que concluir que o Laravel (e outros frameworks similares) não ser uma boa escolha para o desenho de microservices e por conclusão, da web moderna.

Então para não deixar esse pensamento em aberto, de modo que se configure off-topic, fica a minha pergunta exata:

Como implementar o ORM do Laravel em um projeto Web Site/APP que vai consumir end-points de uma API? Vai precisar ter os Models ou os dados já podem vir direto dos COntrollers? Vai ter que replicar toda a Base de dados nas migrations e Models para poder se usar os benefícios das queries? Eu não estou conseguindo enxergar como implementar esse ORM.

Comment: Em uma api para mobile que construí, o uso do laravel ou do lumen ficou muito pesado e precisava considerar a maior quantidade possível de requests com um servidor muito limitado, acabei construindo um framework  MVC customizado com oque eu precisava e apenas instalando o Eloquent como ORM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hoje estou trabalhando em um projeto que optamos trabalhar com serviços (APIs) pela facilidade de crescimento do produto e parcerias a serem criadas assim aumentando o valor agregado de nosso produto.

Confesso que é algo bem árduo e não tão lindo como parece ser, temos sim muitos benefícios nessa abordagem, como: equipe mais bem definida, deploys mais enxutos, liberdade de tecnologias (cuidado), nesse endereço possui uma explicação das [vantagens](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/microservices-architecture-retail-rajesh-gundapaneni) de microservices.

Utilizamos até o momento Laravel 5 em 95% da APIs, por que ? Como nosso time conhece bem Laravel e ele se encaixou bem para resolver os domínios propostos do nosso negócio, aplicamos ele e isso facilitou na criação de pacotes para auxiliar em toda a stack. Exemplos:

- Pacote que traz informações da API como versão do Laravel, ambiente, endpoints entre outras informação.
- Nossa SDK que possui acesso a todos os endpoits das APIs usada em nossos clientes que são Laravel e na comunicação de serviços entre serviços.
- Resource server, esse é para validar escopos de acesso do token gerado no servidor de autenticação e assim validando endpoints.
- E vários outros para auxiliar a stack.

Em outras palavras não perdemos quase nada do laravel apenas o eloquent que é um ORM utilizado por ele para acesso a camada de banco de dados. E isso faz todo sentido se ele é uma aplicação cliente que consome a APIs não acessa a camada de banco de dados diretamente, consome nossa camada de negócio que é um serviço que esta ligado ao um domínio especifico da nossa aplicação. Assim posso ter clientes em javascript, python, java e etc.

Uma das nossas APIs é em NodeJS para servir nossos recursos de pub-sub do Redis assim criando um servidor broadcast para suprir aplicação que necessitam de funcionalidade "real-time" utilizando websocket nesse [link](https://medium.com/@avinicius.adorno/a-necessidade-de-criar-um-servidor-web-socket-63a7c56a1698) explico a ideia.

Com a abordagem de serviços sentimos dificuldades nos testes de integração entre as APIs, no servidor de autenticação OAuth2, nos processos de deploy   utilizado docker assim facilitando fazer deploys em todos os ambientes development, stating, testig e production. Mas esperamos colher bons frutos a longo prazo.

Não se preocupe em perder o eloquent na aplicação cliente pois você pode ter parceiros criando aplicações em cima de suas APIs com qualquer linguagem ou paradigma, isso é a mágica das APIs você da liberdade de nascerem projetos sensacionais em cima de suas APIs sendo públicas ou privadas. Foque todas suas forças nas suas APIs.

Comment: Anderson, obrigado pela explicacao. Eh muito bom o seu artigo. Vc poderia explorar muito mais esse tema. POr favor, se vc tiver mais alguns me avise.

Comment: Vlw espero que tenha passado a minha visão de forma clara. 

No momento estou escrevendo mais sobre Machine Learning mas, é provável que faça alguns posts sobre como arquitetar sistemas distribuídos.

Answer (score 1):

> Por outro lado, pensando no esquema do desenho acima, como seria a
>   implementação de um Web Site/APP que somente consome end-points de uma
>   API?

Você irá consumir através da camada HTTP, utilizando Guzzle ou qualquer outro HTTP client. Como citado na resposta acima construimos SDKs para que nossas aplicações que utilizam laravel possam consumir os serviços de uma maneira mais simples. Será possivel também consumir suas APIs com qualquer outra linguagem.

> Como implementar o ORM do Laravel em um projeto Web Site/APP que vai
>   consumir end-points de uma API? Vai precisar ter os Models ou os dados
>   já podem vir direto dos COntrollers? Vai ter que replicar toda a Base
>   de dados nas migrations e Models para poder se usar os benefícios das
>   queries?

Você não irá utilizar nenhum ORM nesse ponto, pois os dados/regras de negócio vão estar concentradas nas APIs, então você não terá necessidade de manipular banco de dados na aplicação cliente.

Apenas reforçando, não se preocupe em perder o eloquent no client ou o as views com blade nas APIs, pois você poderá usufruir de outros recursos do framework.

Comment: Valeu pela explicacao Leonardo. Obrigado